# Infinite recursive loop with QPluginLoader::instance()

Tags: c++, qt, plugins

I have a conceptual problem I would like to discuss. First I made an automatic system for plugin loading that works like this:

1) It is given the plugin file names or path(s) where to look.

2) It then can be queried with an interface pointer and it will cast in it an appropriate plugin when found (optionally with further conditions).

The templated function for finding the implementation looks like this:

```
template<tInterface> tInterface *implementation(const Requirements &req = Requierements())
{
    tInterface *interface = nullptr;

    for(QPluginLoader *loader : loaders(req)) //returns list of plugins that meet requirements in req
    {
        interface = qobject_cast<tInterface*>(loader.instance())

        if(interface)
            break;
    }

    return interface;
}
```

According to Qt documentation the plugin `instance()` (returning the root component) should be "shared" between all QPluginLoader objects operating on that same file. Well I found out it is not the case. The above code will loop infinitely when there is a call to it from within the plugin constructor (or in any constructor that is called by the root one). Because such a call will instantiate that same plugin (among others) to test for a requested implementation that will trigger yet another call and so forth. It works fine only when called outside of plugin constructors...

I am trying to figure out a solution that would allow me to use it even in constructors of plugins. So far I cannot think of a way or mechanism that would stop the loop hence my question here. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: I don't fully understand - are you saying that your plugin's constructor is calling recurrently a code, which loads the same plugin yet again? Why would you even want plugin recurrently loading plugins from constructor?

Comment: @Googie Well it does so unintentionally. Basically I do this: load plugin X with this code that in its constructor load plugin Y using this function. And because the function works in a way so that it loads each available plugin and test it against the requested interface it might (unintentionally) load the same plugin that called it again calling its constructor etc. creating the loop.

Comment: You should have exactly one `QPluginLoader` per each plugin file. This way you can track loaded plugins. Also I think you misunderstood Qt documentation about "shared instance" of plugin among multiple `QPluginLoader` instances. Qt docs are only telling you, that each time you call `QPluginLoader::instance()` of the same loader, you will get the same plugin object. If you load plugin with two different plugin loaders, you will end up with two different plugin instances. So... keep one loader per plugin and track loaders.

Comment: @Googie I am doing just that but the problem is that the call to QPluginLoader::instance() is looping because the plugin is being instantiated again (via the same QPluginLoader pointer) inside the call to instance(). In other words instance() calls load() that calls plugin constructor. If I in that constructor requests that plugin again (during the search for another plugin) the QPluginLoader object that requested it has not yet finished its instance() and cannot give me the same QObject* root component hence it attempts it again = looping. At least this is my understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is rather simple. The QPluginLoader object on which is currently called `instance()` must be "locked" prior to that call of `instance()` so that subsequent calls of instance on it are prohibited until the first call is finished - sort of a mutex behaviour. This prevents the described problem of calling `instance()` inside the call to `instance()` on the same QPluginLoader (happens because of the search through all plugins looking for possible implementations of the interface, see OP for function that does that).

I accomplished it with tracking the QPluginLoader objects that are "in use" releasing them after the `instance()` finished. This allows me to request plugins in constructors of other plugins with the only restriction that I cannot request the same plugin or any "parent" plugin in the loading hierarchy:

If constructor(s) of plugin X requests plugin Y that (in its constructor(s)) requests plugin Z then Z cannot request Y nor X (and Y cannot request X) in its own constructor(s). Such attempts would fail returning nullptr interface.

For completeness sake here is the modified function:

```
template<tInterface> tInterface *implementation(const Requirements &req = Requierements())
{
    tInterface *interface = nullptr;

    for(QPluginLoader *loader : loaders(req)) 
    //loaders() returns list of plugins that meet requirements in req
    //AND ARE NOT PRESENT IN m_Locked
    {
        m_Locked << loader;
        interface = qobject_cast<tInterface*>(loader.instance())
        m_Locked.removeOne(loader);

        if(interface)
            break;
    }

    return interface;
}
```